# Can anybody explain the deep reason why here df.replace( ) end up with AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'? Thanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

```
# here is the code:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': \['  x', 'y ', ' z ', 'w   ', None\], "b": \[1, 2, 3, 4, 5\]}, dtype='string')
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
df.replace('x', 'X')
```

```
C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\missing.py:95: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  new_mask = arr == x

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [52], line 4
      2 df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['  x', 'y ', ' z ', 'w   ', None], "b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, dtype='string')
      3 df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
----> 4 df.replace('x', 'X')

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:5728, in DataFrame.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   5715 @deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments(
   5716     version=None, allowed_args=["self", "to_replace", "value"]
   5717 )
   (...)
   5726     method: Literal["pad", "ffill", "bfill"] | lib.NoDefault = lib.no_default,
   5727 ) -> DataFrame | None:
-> 5728     return super().replace(
   5729         to_replace=to_replace,
   5730         value=value,
   5731         inplace=inplace,
   5732         limit=limit,
   5733         regex=regex,
   5734         method=method,
   5735     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:7280, in NDFrame.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   7274         new_data = self._mgr.replace_regex(
   7275             to_replace=to_replace,
   7276             value=value,
   7277             inplace=inplace,
   7278         )
   7279     else:
-> 7280         new_data = self._mgr.replace(
   7281             to_replace=to_replace, value=value, inplace=inplace
   7282         )
   7283 else:
   7284     raise TypeError(
   7285         f'Invalid "to_replace" type: {repr(type(to_replace).__name__)}'
   7286     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:470, in BaseBlockManager.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace)
    468 assert not is_list_like(to_replace)
    469 assert not is_list_like(value)
--> 470 return self.apply(
    471     "replace", to_replace=to_replace, value=value, inplace=inplace
    472 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:352, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    350         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    351     else:
--> 352         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    353 except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    354     if not ignore_failures:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:592, in Block.replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, mask)
    589     return [self] if inplace else [self.copy()]
    591 if mask is None:
--> 592     mask = missing.mask_missing(values, to_replace)
    593 if not mask.any():
    594     # Note: we get here with test_replace_extension_other incorrectly
    595     #  bc _can_hold_element is incorrect.
    596     return [self] if inplace else [self.copy()]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\missing.py:98, in mask_missing(arr, values_to_mask)
     95         new_mask = arr == x
     96         if not isinstance(new_mask, np.ndarray):
     97             # usually BooleanArray
---> 98             new_mask = new_mask.to_numpy(dtype=bool, na_value=False)
     99         mask |= new_mask
    101 if na_mask.any():

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

Thank you for taking time to read this!

I have read:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47480
It seems like not the same issue with <NA> value.
I also read the docs:
[pandas.DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)
This happens when use dtype='string'
This won't happend when dtype = None or str or 'str' 
I was expecting the code is executed without error / exception

Update: pandas and python version:
Python 3.10.7 and pandas 1.5.3

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on Pandas 1.3.4.

Comment: Reproduced on pandas 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Your `applymap` call changes the dtypes from `string` to `object`. Convert again with [`convert_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) to avoid the error:

```
df.convert_dtypes().replace('x', 'X')
```

Output:

```
      a  b
0     X  1
1     y  2
2     z  3
3     w  4
4  <NA>  5
```

dtypes:

```
# initial

a    string
b    string
dtype: object

# after applymap

a    object
b    object
dtype: object

# after convert_dtypes

a    string
b    string
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

It feels like a possible bug in pandas and other people have raised this before.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47101#issuecomment-1773385803

You could override that point in your pandas code on core/missing.py line 95.

> new_mask = arr == x

For example,

> new_mask = np.array([i == x for i in arr])

might do the trick.

Comment: "might do the trick"? This is why are are required to do [mre]. Please support your answer with your output obtained using provided input data.

Comment: @OCa I'm having difficulty reproducing OP's bug. I can't on pandas 2 or 1.3.5 for example. On 1.3.5, they seem to be aware of the elementwise issue and it raises a warning "missing.py:94: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison"
When I was running into this issue with QPython's QList, I replaced that line with new_mask = np.equal(arr, x) and that fixed an exception at the same line resulting from bool.to_array()

Comment: Ah yes. Some of this is good information that you can post in your answer. Comments may be deleted at some point.